# Web api: [FromBody] always returns list with count of 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have an api (post method) that takes in a list of transport objects. when I test using swagger, the list comes back with a count of 0 (not null), even though I am sending a List of transports. In below scenario I would assume the count should be 1. Here is a small sample of the Json I am sending.

```
[{
  "type": "",
  "attributes": {
    "TransportId":"",
    "Status": "string",
    "Action": "test",
    "ActionBy": "string",
    "ActionDate": "",
    "PackingGroupID": "a713eb0a-5682-4cb5"}]
```

Here is the api call:

```
[HttpPost, Route("bulk")]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Transport>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveTransports([FromBody] List<Transport> transports, string packingGroupId)
{      
    var resulttransports = await _transportService.SaveTransportsAsync(transports, packingGroupId);
    if (resulttransports != null)
        ConvertTransportDateToTimezone(ref resulttransports);
    return Ok(resulttransports);
}
```

Bel:ow is an image of result

[image: Image of result]

Comment: Your JSON is not valid - it needs one more `}` before the `]`. You can use https://jsonlint.com to check for JSON syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding one more } at the end.  I use JsonFormatter to always test my JSON.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

```
   [{
  "type": "",
  "attributes": {
    "TransportId":"",
    "Status": "string",
    "Action": "test",
    "ActionBy": "string",
    "ActionDate": "",
    "PackingGroupID": "a713eb0a-5682-4cb5"}}]
```

Comment: yes , I only posted a partial of the Json because it is so long but  invalid Json was issue.